# Circuit Analysis Confusion

Tags: amplifier, analog

Circuit (Mosfet Active Load Differential Amplifier):

[image]

**Note:** This is not homework. I want to be able analyze circuits well, and currently my understanding of circuits is weak.

1. In my textbook, I do not see the the \$1/g_{m}\$ resistance on transistor Q4, why is that?
2. Since a short exist between \$V_{o}\$ and \$V_{icm}\$, does that mean \$V_{o}=V_{icm}\$?

Comment: Are you aware Q3/Q4 is a current mirror? The current is "programmed" through I(D,Q3), the V(GS,Q3) gate voltage that is required is applied to Q4. It is important that Q3 and Q4 are well matched (identical). I(D,Q3) is "forced copied" to I(D,Q4).

Comment: Can you elaborate on #2, I don't see V(cm), not sure which short you are referring to.

Comment: @jippie: In the bottom circle, don't you see in Q2, there exist a short between Vo and Vicm. I know they are matched, for Q3 they show the 1/gm resistance but for Q4, they do not show 1/gm resistance. Reference:Sedra Microelectronics

Comment: Ah you should edit your question then. You mix up CM and ICM, which confused me. Also I don't see a short between pins in the lower right circle. Q3 has gate and drain shorted. Unfortunately don't have access to the book.

Comment: @jippie: I totally forgot that a transistor is a back to back diode.

Comment: These are MOSFET's, not BJT's (Bipolar Junction Transistors). Not sure what the confusion is, but I'm getting the impression you misinterpret(ed) the MOSFET symbol. BTW to make things easier [...] there are various symbols that slightly vary but all are MOSFET's: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0c/IGFET_P-Ch_Enh_Labelled.svg/120px-IGFET_P-Ch_Enh_Labelled.svg.png  Check wikipedia for BJT symbols.

Comment: @jippie: I know they are mosfets, but when you apply the T model, there exist a short from output potential to the Vicm potential. T-model: http://examcrazy.com/Engineering/Electronics-Communication/images/MOSFET_as_an_Amplifier/image038.jpg

Comment: @Fisanmala, using the T model there is still no short from \$v_o\$ to \$v_{icm}\$. The dependent current source \$g_mv_{gs}\$ is between them.

Comment: @ZekeR: Yeah, when I realized that that, you do not know how happy I felt, because there is a voltage accross dependent and teachers never mentioned that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

from what I can see, I would say your textbook is the Sedra&Smith electronic book right?

You should check the chapter on MOSFETS(Chapter 5 in my edition), they demonstrate every possible configuration and the results.

Here is the resume table that they got on MOSFET

[image]

For the second point, you are wrong there isn't a short between Vo and Vicm actually, if you analyse correctly this problem you end with the CMRR of the pair
Regards MathieuL

Comment: The mosfet you are refering too is in Common drain, I won't do the complete demos because it is quite heavy but I can link you this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_drain